# Understanding a proof that, if $|a-1|+|b-1|=|a|+|b|=|a+1|+|b+1|$, then the minimum value of $|a-b|$, over distinct reals $a$ and $b$, is $2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value, reference-works

I saw this epic question in *Advanced Problems in Mathematics* by Vikas Gupta:

> If $$|a-1|+|b-1|=|a|+|b|=|a+1|+|b+1|$$ then find the minimum value of $|a-b|$, where $a$ and $b$ are distinct real numbers.

*My Solution*:

[image]

So my answer is correct, and I happily turned to the solution page to see what the author has written, and here's the MINDBLOWING solution I found:

[image]

Despite reading the solution many times, I'm still **unable to understand what was the motivation behind taking $f(x)=|x-a|+|x-b|$ and supposing $a>b$. Also on what basis did he write $f(0)=f(1)=(-1)$ and the remaining steps**.

Could you please explain the motivation behind each step written by the author? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I also wanted to add, if you guys know any better ways than the 2 ways given posted by me, I would love to know that as well:)

Comment: For me, it would have been easier to undersand had the author written $f(x)=\mid a-x\mid+\mid b-x\mid$, but $\mid x-a\mid=\mid a-x\mid$ so, in fact it is the same thing. $f(0)=f(1)=f(-1)$ is the assumption in the question rephrased in terms of $f(x)$.

Comment: the author has written $f(0) = f(1)= \color{blue}{f(-1)}$. Substitute the values of $x$ to see if you get the expression : $|a-1|+|b-1|=|a|+|b|=|a+1|+|b+1|$

Comment: This can be seen as a taxicab distance from $(a,b)$ to $(1,1),$ $(0,0)$ and $(-1,-1)$ are all the same.

$|a-b|$ is the shortest taxicab distance from $(a,b)$ to the line $y=x.$ 
Not sure if this helps.

Comment: $f(0)=f(1)=f(-1)$ is just our initial condition, $$|a-1|+|b-1|=|a|+|b|=|a+1|+|b+1|.$$

Comment: @DS Yes we do but what made him think and draw a graph like that. That's what I wanted to know

Comment: If you exchange $a$ and $b$ in the question, it makes no difference. So, since they are distinct, one of them must be greater. So, we assume $a$ is greater

Comment: With $a>b$, try finding the value of $f(x)$ if $a\ge x \ge b$.

Comment: $f(x)$ is the taxicab distance from $(a,b)$ to $(x,x).$ We know the minimum of $f(x)$ is $|a-b|,$ from my comment above.

Comment: Once you get that $f(x)$ is constant in $a \ge x \ge b$, try finding an expression for $x>a$ and $x<b$ cases. Is $f(x)$ constant in these two cases?

Comment: You can pick $a>b$ just by symmetry. If $a<b,$ we can switch $(a',b')=(b,a)$ and get the same question with $a'>b'.$ This is a standard trick to simplify a question.

Comment: You said your answer is correct, but it is not clear to me why you consider only 5 cases.

Comment: You said you know that, but you asked "On what basis, ..." which implies a logical basis, and not "On what instinct or intuition ..."

Comment: generally speaking, it comes mostly from experience and some playing around with it. Elegant solutions usually come after you have discovered a not-so-elegant one with which you are a bit dissatisfied and work to improve it. There is no "magic" ability one can just learn to start churning out beautiful solutions.

Comment: Note, the given answer concludes the wrong thing: $|a-b|\leq 2.$ That would imply the maximum value of $|a-b|$ is $2,$ not the minimum. Everything before the last two steps is okay, but they botched those steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a big error in the last steps of the shorter proof, and a mild gap.

First, the motivation.

Intuitively, this is a question about the so-called [taxicab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). The taxicab distance between $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$ is $$|x-a|+|y-b|.$$

$|a|+|b|,$ $|a-1|+|b-1|$ and $|a+1|+|b+1|$ are the distances between $(a,b)$ and $(1,1),$ $(0,0),$ and $(-1,-1),$ respectively. And $|a-b|$ is the shortest distance from $(a,b)$ to the line $y=x.$

So everything about this seems to be about the taxicab distances between $(a,b)$ and points $(x,x).$

So it is natural to define the distance from $(a,b)$ to $(x,x)$:

$$f(x)=|a-x|+|b-x|$$

and try to learn about this function.

---

The big error in the given proof is the last two lines. The statement $b\leq-1\leq a\leq 1$ is wrong.

It should be $$b\leq-1<1\leq a,\tag1$$ and thus $a-b=|a-b|\geq 2.$

The reason for $(1)$ is the skipped step.

$f(x)$ is strictly decreasing when $x<b$ and strictly increasing when $x>a,$ and so the only way three distinct values $u,v,w$ have $f(u)=f(v)=f(w)$ is for the three values to be in $[b,a].$

But we know $f(0)=f(-1)=f(1),$ so $0,1,-1\in[b,a].$

The "shape" of $f$ is the key. We want to show that $f^{-1}(d)$ has at most two points for any $d>|a-b|,$ and for that you need to know not just that $f$ is constant on $[b,a],$ but that the functions is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,b)$ and strictly increasing on $(a,+\infty).$

---

So we get a stronger result:

> If $u<v<w$ and $f(u)=f(v)=f(w),$ then $|a-b|\geq w-u.$

---

Picking $a>b$ is possible because the question is symmetric. You could theoretically prove it in two cases, $a>b$ and $b>a,$ but the second case would be exactly the same, with $a,b$ reversed. So we often do only the first case if it is obvious the second case is exactly the same.

Mathematicians will often say things like "Without loss of generality, we can assume $a>b.$" This usually means that we are proving for some subset of cases, but we can easily get the general case back from this subset.

Comment: For the record, the answer in the book also has a mistake in the illustration: $f(x)$ should be $a-b$ on the constant part.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it is a better method, but it seems more natural to me: first of all, remember that if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, then $|x-y|$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$.

Therefore, $|a-1|+|b-1|=|a|+|b|$ implies that $a$ and $b$ cannot both be nonpositive. Otherwise, from the remark above (or by direct computation), we would have $|a|+|b|<|a-1|+|b-1|$. By symmetry, $a$ and $b$ cannot be both larger than or equal to $1$.

Similarly, $|a+1|+|b+1|$ implies that $a$ and $b$ cannot both be nonnegative and cannot be both smaller than or equal to $-1$. By symmetry, we can assume that $a\le b$. It follows that $a\le-1<1\le b$.

So $|a-b|\ge 1-(-1)=2$. Since we can check that, for $a=-1$ and $b=1$, all constraints are satisfied, the smallest value for $|a-b|$ is indeed $2$.